# Rails and query datepicker, how to get date in field more tied to pop-up calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

The text field and the pop-up are linked in that I can use the calendar and the field shows the correct value (or blank) initially.

But they are not linked in that the pop-up is always for the current month, not the month of the db field value.

```
  = f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size: 10
```

I tried adding `,value: @user.content_date` but it didn't help.

My jquery is:

```
// jQueryUI Date Picker:
$(function (){
        $(".datepick").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
});
```

I added the dateFormat per dimuch which seemed promising but it didn't help yet.

I also tried altFormat but it did't help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have different date formats in the datepicker and content_date field. Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wKNXx/

Comment: This seemed promising but I couldn't get it to work.  Added my code to the question above.

Comment: But +1 for the dateFormat info that I didn't have initially.  It didn't work for me yet but looks like part of whatever answer I have (I've added it now to the question).